# Html bootstrap table not appearing on screen

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am having trouble displaying a table in html. When I hardcode values in the table they appear but when using angularjs they do not appear. So I think the problem has to do with something in angualrjs. Here is my html code that I am trying to display:

```
 <div class="container">
 <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
 <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>            
 <table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Friends</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="Friends in AllUsersFriends">
        <td>{{Friends}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Here is my controller.js code:

```
    socket.on("AllFriends",function (Friends){
  $log.log('so the friends are');
  $scope.AllUsersFriends=Friends;
  console.log($scope.AllUsersFriends);
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

I am receiving an array via flask-socketio and then I set that array to my $scope.AllUsersFriends array I created. I see the data in the console but no rows appear on the screen. How do I get my data to appear on the screen? Thanks.

Comment: In your console.log are you passing any HTML? Perhaps there is bad mark up that is causing a row or <td> to end prematurely which may cause the table to not appear or maybe a class that sets the table to display:none. Just a thought

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr><th>Friends</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in friends"><td>{{x.name}}</td></tr>
 </table>

<script>
//App declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.friends = [{name: "Peter"},{name:"Laila"},{name:"Rosy"}];

});

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Hope, it solves!

Answer (score 0):

so I fixed my problem and the problem was that data from the array was actually being updated but I have different pages in my application and data was getting lost as soon as I change the page then I solved it by creating the same array in a service so that the changes were global and the data would not be wiped from the array. So the table was always showing up it just did not have any data to display.
Thanks alot